# Configuring GSSAPI and Cyrus SASL

Tags: sasl, gssapi, cyrus

I've been trying to configure GSSAPI and Cyrus SASL, following [this](https://www.cyrusimap.org/docs/cyrus-sasl/2.1.25/gssapi.php) guide.

It seems pretty straightforward, except for the very first step, "1. Compile the Cyrus-SASL distribution with the GSSAPI plugin for your favorite GSS-API mechanism."

I can't figure this out, and I have nowhere else to go. I've looked through the output of "./configure --help" to try to understand how to include certain plugins, but it isn't made obvious if the options I enter while configuring are valid or not. For example, I can type "./configure --enable-asdf" and it goes through without a hiccup. So I have no idea if I'm doing things properly, or even close to, when trying to set this up.

Things I've tried: "./configure --enable-gssapi" (amongst many slight and vast variations to this command). After configuring and running "make" and "make install", I've tried entering "pluginviewer  | grep -i gssapi" to see if I have the GSSAPI mechanism installed. Sure enough, I do not.

Comment: Though, I know what to do, this is neither for Stack Overflow, nor have you shown what your platform and versions are.

Comment: @Michael-O
I am running Ubuntu 16.04 on a laptop with x86_64 architecture. 
Version is cyrus-sasl-2.1.26. 
Where should I take this issue instead of posting to this site?

Comment: there is absolutely no need to compile that yourself. UBuntun has all necessary packages. Cyrus SASL with GSSAPI mech is a separate module.